# fix Input/output error tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

While working with the [PYTHON PLAYS GTAV](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5)  I am able to collect the data using grabscreen and save it using the collect_data script, but when trying to train the data using the train_model script I get the errors mentioned below due to empty MODEL_NAME and PREV_MODEL. Tried entering the location of the collected data file but was no help.

```
import numpy as np
from grabscreen import grab_screen
import cv2
import time
import os
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from collections import deque
from models import inception_v3 as googlenet
from random import shuffle


FILE_I_END = 1860

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 270
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 30
MODEL_NAME = ''
PREV_MODEL = ''

LOAD_MODEL = True

wl = 0
sl = 0
al = 0
dl = 0

wal = 0
wdl = 0
sal = 0
sdl = 0
nkl = 0

w = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
s = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
a = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
d = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
wa = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
wd = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
sa = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
sd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
nk = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

model = googlenet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3, LR, output=9, model_name=MODEL_NAME)

if LOAD_MODEL:
    model.load(PREV_MODEL)
    print('We have loaded a previous model!!!!')


# iterates through the training files


for e in range(EPOCHS):
    #data_order = [i for i in range(1,FILE_I_END+1)]
    data_order = [i for i in range(1,FILE_I_END+1)]
    shuffle(data_order)
    for count,i in enumerate(data_order):

        try:
            file_name = 'F:/PythonGTA/pygta5-master/training_data-{}.npy'.format(i)
            # full file info
            train_data = np.load(file_name)
            print('training_data-{}.npy'.format(i),len(train_data))

##            # [   [    [FRAMES], CHOICE   ]    ] 
##            train_data = []
##            current_frames = deque(maxlen=HM_FRAMES)
##            
##            for ds in data:
##                screen, choice = ds
##                gray_screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
##
##
##                current_frames.append(gray_screen)
##                if len(current_frames) == HM_FRAMES:
##                    train_data.append([list(current_frames),choice])


            # #
            # always validating unique data: 
            #shuffle(train_data)
            train = train_data[:-50]
            test = train_data[-50:]

            X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,3)
            Y = [i[1] for i in train]

            test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,3)
            test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

            model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
                snapshot_step=2500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)


            if count%10 == 0:
                print('SAVING MODEL!')
                model.save(MODEL_NAME)

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

**Error**

```
DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file F:\PythonGTA\pygta5-master: Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: F:\PythonGTA\pygta5-master : Access is denied.

; Input/output error
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save_1/Const_0_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2/_311 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_312_save_1/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```